# Wrong number casting in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

The following code give me the answer "float".

```
let z : AnyObject = Int(2)

if z is Float {
    print("float")
} else {
    print("int")
}
```

Is it correct?

I'm using Xcode 7.3.1.

Comment: Your code would not be executed. First line will show error messge "Value of type Int does not confirm to specified type Anyobject"

Comment: actually it will execute, check it in playground

Comment: Just checked too and it does not works.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I'm suspecting that when it wrapped as `AnyObject`, it's maybe stored as an `NSNumber`, and using `is Int/Double/Float` yields to true.

Comment: I just tested this in a playground and interestingly switching to `Any` makes it work as expected.

Comment: It seem  that when you declare z as AnyObject, and initialize with an Int (or Double, or Float), it consider that z is a number, then all compare "is" with Double or Float or Int will return true if it can convert to that type.

Comment: Yeah!!! 'Any' works correctly. Thank you!

Comment: @Brduca It doesn't work for you because you don't have `import Foundation` at the top, probably.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In pure Swift, this line:

```
let z: AnyObject = Int(2)
```

gives **error: value of type 'Int' does not conform to specified type 'AnyObject'**

That is because *AnyObject* holds objects (instances of classes), but it doesn't hold structs or primitive types.

When **Foundation** is imported (through `import UIKit`, `import Cocoa`, or `import Foundation`), Swift will convert `Int`, `Float`, `Double`, and `Bool` into an `NSNumber`.  You can see that this is true by printing:

```
print(z.dynamicType)
```

> ```
> __NSCFNumber
> ```

That is the internal representation of `NSNumber`.

`NSNumber` is an object which wraps primitive types.  It is used in Objective-C to store these values in an `NSArray` which holds `AnyObject`s.

The interesting thing about `NSNumber` is that you can put in all of those types (`Int`, `Double`, `Float`, `Bool`) and then take the value out as any of those types.  Consider:

```
let z: AnyObject = 3.14

print(z as! Int)     // 3
print(z as! Float)   // 3.14
print(z as! Bool)    // true
```

So, when you query an `NSNumber` with `is Int`, `is Float`, `is Double`, or `is Bool`, it will always return `true` meaning "I can be that type if you want".

---

#### Using Any instead of AnyObject

If instead, you use `Any`, then you'll get the expected result:

```
let z: Any = 2

if z is Float {
    print("float")
} else {
    print("int")    // prints "int"
}
```

That is because `Any` can store any type, not just instances of classes, so the underlying type remains an `Int`:

```
print(z.dynamicType)
```

> ```
> Int
> ```

---

#### Why does Swift convert Ints to NSNumber when assigned to AnyObject?

This is done to make working with Objective-C based frameworks such as *Cocoa* and *Cocoa Touch* easier.  It enables you to pass an array such as `[2, 3.14, "hello"]` into a function that expects an `NSArray`.  This is certainly easier to use than `NSArray(arrayLiteral: NSNumber(integer: 2), NSNumber(float: 3.14), NSString(string: "hello"))`.

Answer (score 0):

By casting to AnyObject it internally converted to NSCFNumber, so all this validations will pass:

```
import Foundation

let z:AnyObject = Int(2) 

print(z.dynamicType) // "__NSCFNumber\n"

let isInt = z is Int // true
let isFloat = z is Float // true
let isDouble = z is Double // true
```